# Change to root user in script without entering password

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

First I have to say there are lot of similar question asked in Stackoverflow but nothing is helpful for me.

My requirement is I have a script which gets root password as script arguments from other program[Most probably java/Python], after getting the password I want to execute few commands as root user like editing the ip-tables and so on which only root user have access . The current script is executed by non-sudo user so , I cannot pass the password like

```
echo "Password" | sudo -S cat /ect/sysConfig/iptables
```

Is there any way to pass the password to the script without prompting and execute the script?

Comment: Adding passwords in scripts are a really bad idea and is a practice you should avoid at all cost. You can add the user to the sudoers file (safer) or do an ssh key exchange. Editing files which are owned by root, should generally be done as (1) make a copy of the file (2) edit the copy, (3) test the edited copy (4) copy as sudo in place. So the only right the user should have is to copy that particular file over.

Comment: Very important read: [Hiding Password in Shell Scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212329) on [unix.se]

Comment: First , I am not adding password in script. As I mentioned earlier those are coming from other external program.  
Second , files owned by root which we are editing are custom files and mostly we are adding some values not deleting any files

Comment: Sorry, this was not clear from your question. Could you maybe rewrite it a bit?

Comment: Sure, I did, Please let me know whether my update makes clear now

Comment: What we are missing a bit is how, scriptwise you see this process happening. Can you give us an example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: I would recommend that an alternate user run the script, and add that user into your /etc/sudoers (or use visudo) and include the "no passwd" option for that identity.  Additionally, you can lock down that user to run only specific commands.## Allows people in group wheel to run all commands
# %wheel        ALL=(ALL)       ALL

## Same thing without a password
# %wheel        ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL

## Allows members of the users group to shutdown this system
# %users  localhost=/sbin/shutdown -h now